# php based document management system

Tags: php, integration, dms

Can anyone recommend a simple document management system with a decent web service interface?

I am looking at using it to provide metadata management of uploaded files from a ajax web application.

I've tried KnowledgeTree, but it's web service layer seems to be a bit complicated. Is there anything else out there with the similar features but a better integration backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DocMgr](http://www.docmgr.org) have just released a new version where they have a xml based web service API. I have not tried the new version yet, but the document management system is great (IMO way better that knowledge tree), and is worth a try.

One note is that it runs on PostgreSQL for speed, so this could be an issue if you are planing on running this at a web host, but I reccomend testing it out!

Comment: Looks great, got it integrated pretty quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to hear that you found the KnowledgeTree web services interface complex. We'd love to hear more about what we could do to improve it. Feel free to drop us a mail on community |AT| KnowledgeTree | DOT | com

Have you taken a look at our latest documentation?
http://docs.knowledgetree.com/api/latest/

It covers the complete API and includes loads of examples to help get you started.

Phil (KnowledgeTree Team)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.opendocman.com/