# File Management system in Php

Tags: php, file-upload, file-management

I have my system backed up on a server (Docs, Videos, Music, etc.) 
I have only FTP access (can't really do anything fancy) 
However I can run PHP and MySQL programs (pretty basic). 
I was wondering about a good complete system that would let me 
upload, control and manage the files I have there (including security features) 
so that I would be able to edit some docs on the fly, listen to streaming music and upload more files if I wanted to.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635396/php-based-document-management-system

Comment: Thanks a bunch, definitely will use that one for my docs, dare I ask if there's a collaboration option there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/

or

http://pfn.sourceforge.net/index.php?opc=1&lg=ing

or

http://navphp.sourceforge.net/

I used the first one and it's pretty good. For media preview I know only http://www.filerun.com/ but it's not open-source.

Comment: So far the Php File Navigator seems to be the best (also checked the phpwebftp mentioned below), however it seems that none of them has been updated in quite a while, also, I don't see some media management features (song streaming mainly)

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in the past and it's open source so you can extend as needed.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwebftp/